# how to edit original table in laravel migration?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

My question is how to edit original table in laravel migration?

That is, suppose to there are two table have as `Teacher` and `Children`. As well as Student table has **foreign key as TeacherId.** (Teacher_id refer to TeacherId in Teacher table)
Some error reason I want to drop Teacher table or edit Teacher table. Then general error occur without original key table cannot had foreign key.

**So how can I drop the Teacher table or edit Teacher table without drop Student table?**
Have some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to drop the foreign key on the your Student table (or maybe the teacher_id column entirely if you no longer have a Teacher table), then you should be able to drop the Teacher table assuming no more foreign keys are referencing the Student table.

Answer (score 0):

You should code your **laravel** `migrations` in a way, so you can revert it all back, under `down()` method.

Sometimes you get stuck, in a way that, `migrate` or `migrate:rollback` command produces an error.

Then you should modify your db structure, by hand (using mysql command, workbench, or any other sql tools), to bring your migrations to working again...

And finally targetting your question...

You cannot **create table** and **add foreign constraints** in one commit to db, so in order, to do that, you need to add new declaration in your migration `up()` like `Table:...` after `Schema:create...` and add your foreign keys here. Remember to do the opposite in `down()` method...